# Reg: MGF and independence

Tags: independence, moment-generating-function

If three random variables X, Y, and Z are pairwise independent, whether U = aZ+bY, V = aY+bX are independent?
I tried using MGF technique and arrived (i don't know its correct or not) as U and V are independent.
However I calculated Cov(U, V) that I feel different from zero. What do I really miss? Pls help on this

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$\operatorname{cov}(U,V)=a^2\operatorname{cov}(Z,Y)+ab\operatorname{cov}(Z,X)+ab\operatorname{cov}(Y,Y)+b^2\operatorname{cov}(Y,X)=ab\operatorname{var}(Y)\geq 0,$$
$U$ and $V$ are **dependent** if 
$\operatorname{cov}(U,V) =ab\operatorname{var}(Y) > 0$.

If $\operatorname{cov}(U,V) = 0$, it must be that

- $Y$ is a degenerate random variable (a.k.a. a constant a.s.) so that $U$ and $V$ are essentially scaled versions of independent random variables $Z$ and $X$ and so $U$ and $V$ are independent.

or

- at least one of $a$ and $b$ is zero and so once again $U$ and $V$ are scaled
  versions of independent random variables and therefore are independent.

---

I don't know how you decided via moment-generating functions that
$U$ and $V$ are independent, but the calculations must be incorrect.

Comment: A third option is that $U$ and $V$ do not have a covariance. (I don't think we can trust the OP on this.) We don't even know whether $Y$ has a variance!

Comment: @whuber Yes indeed, but I didn't want to muddy the issue any further. For example, the OP might not have even considered the possibility that one of $a$ or $b$ could be $0$.